# Help building a mac application from python using py2app?

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I have a Tkinter app written in python, and I want to make "native" (easy to run) mac and windows executables of it. I've successfully built a windows .exe using py2exe, but the equivalent process with py2app isn't working.

Here's my setup.py:
`from setuptools import setup
import sys

MAIN_SCRIPT  = "myapp.py"
WINDOWS_ICON = "myicon.ico"
MAC_ICON     = "myicon.icns"

if sys.platform in ("win32", "win64"): # does win64 exist?
    import py2exe
    setup( windows=[{ "script":MAIN_SCRIPT,
                      "icon_resources":[(0x0004, WINDOWS_ICON)]
                   }],
         )
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    import py2app
    setup( app=[MAIN_SCRIPT], # doesn't include the icon yet
           setup_requires=["py2app"],
         )`

I just `cd` to my app directory and run `python setup.py py2app`. The .app appears without errors, but it crashes on launch with "myapp has encountered a fatal error, and will now terminate."

I'm running Snow Leopard, and I've tried this with both the standard Apple Python 2.6 and python25 from MacPorts. I read somewhere that it's better to use a different Python because py2app won't bundle the system version in your app.

EDIT: Here's what the mac console has to say about it:
`11/27/10 1:54:44 PM  [0x0-0x80080].org.pythonmac.unspecified.myapp[77495]    dlsym(0x10b120, Py_SetProgramName): symbol not found
11/27/10 1:54:46 PM [0x0-0x80080].org.pythonmac.unspecified.myapp[77495]    0x99274242
11/27/10 1:54:46 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[185]  ([0x0-0x80080].org.pythonmac.unspecified.myapp[77495]) Exited with exit code: 255`

Comment: FYI: win64 doesn't exist.  See http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/sys.html#sys.platform .  Also, isn't there an application log/debug flag somewhere in py2app? That would be very helpful in debugging the problem.  I suspect it's an import error somewhere.

Comment: I updated the question with console output. py2app itself goes into debugging mode with [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) if it needs to, but it's been finishing correctly. I wonder if I can add pdb to the running app too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with using Snow Leopard. I tried it on a Leopard machine at school and it builds fine.